# How to select last months and calculate in Codeigniter3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to calculate the **count** variable after I select date from **db** table and calculate from last month as below function

Issue I've select from DB but I  can't check for last month and calculate **count** because I don't want to use **sql** in CI3 query.

Here is my function

```
   public function last_month() {

        $date = date('m', time());
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_agent');
        $q = $this->db->get();
        $count = 0;
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $item) {
//                    echo (int)date("m", strtotime($item->timestamp));
                if ((int)date("m", strtotime($item->timestamp)) == (int)date("m", strtotime($date))) {
                    $count += $item->count;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return $count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly to your wishes MYSQL native functions would be best way to calculate something like that.
If you would like to add months as you started above like 9+9+9, than

```
SELECT SUM(MONTH(NOW())) AS monthCount FROM  `ci_sessions` WHERE `last_activity` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE("{$currentMonth}", '%Y-%m-%d')) - 1;
```

, but if you would like to know just amount of rows fit current month than

```
SELECT COUNT(`last_activity`) AS monthCount FROM  `ci_sessions` WHERE `last_activity` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE("{$currentMonth}", '%Y-%m-%d')) - 1;
```

For passing last day of previous month that you would need to use dynamically in PHP before MySQL you should find it this way for example

```
$currentMonth = date('Y-m-01');
```

Of course you would need to adapt code to fit your tables and column names.

Comment: @Cambodia channel I made some change here now is working as you'd have it expected. Previous version didn't fillful all cases.